# AWS&Node.js : Setting up Credentials using Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, browserify

I want to use aws-sdk in Javascript. So I installed browserify and aws-sdk with nam install. In the Terminals I wrote

```
browserify project/project.js > browser-app.js
```

It creates a browser-app.js for me. Now I want to run some code like this within my browser:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sqs = new AWS.SQS()
var params = {
                MessageBody: JSON.stringify(SOMEJson),
                QueueUrl: QueueURL
            };
sqs.sendMessage(params,function(err, data){
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
                else     console.log(data);
            });
```

My credentials file is in ~/.aws/config

Then I run the code I get the following error message:

```
Error: Missing credentials in config
at credError (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:1018:40)
at Config.getCredentials (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:1057:14)
at Request.VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:3111:26)
at Request.callListeners (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:7214:18)
at Request.emit (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:7190:10)
at Request.emit (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:6042:14)
at Request.transition (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:5449:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:9740:12)
at Request.runTo (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:5821:15)
at Request.send (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:5785:10) CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config
at credError (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:1018:40)
at Config.getCredentials (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:1057:14)
at Request.VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:3111:26)
at Request.callListeners (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:7214:18)
at Request.emit (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:7190:10)
at Request.emit (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:6042:14)
at Request.transition (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:5449:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:9740:12)
at Request.runTo (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:5821:15)
at Request.send (http://localhost:63343/urfado-regex/browser-app.js:5785:10)
```

I also tried to hardcode my credentials with aws.config like this:

```
AWS.config.update({
                accessKeyId: "MYKEY",
                secretAccessKey: "MYSECRETKEY",
                "region": "eu-central-1"
        });
```

I still get the same error. Anybody knows what I could do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When executing from a browser context you have the following options to authenticate

- Using Amazon Cognito to authenticate users
- Using web identity federation to authenticate users
- Hard-coded in your application

Make sure you set 
`AWS.config.update({
                accessKeyId: "MYKEY",
                secretAccessKey: "MYSECRETKEY",
                "region": "eu-central-1"
        });`

before you instantiate the sqs object.

Reference:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html

Comment: I have also a credentials file in .aws
And I am sure that I set up the config before setting up the sis object :(

Comment: i did not realize you are invoking from browser context

Comment: only option you have is Hard-Coding Credentials.. check you have the appropriate permissions for the accesskey setup on aws IAM